# Android - Playing Youtube Videos using Youtube Player API in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-youtube-api

I have tried using WebViews to display Youtube Videos in ListView, what happens is when i scroll off screen and back to the cell the Video was located the Video disappears meaning that the WebView does not render back the WebView with the Video in it. So i tried using YoutubePlayerAPI but i am finding it difficult to understand how i can insert these Videos using the YoutubePlayerAPI.

Could someone please advise?

I have tried using YoutubePlayerView in my ArrayAdapter but i get Inflate errors, i have also created YoutubeBaseActivity and YoutubeFragment but cant understand how i get the layout or ui to display these videos in my ListView Cells.

Comment: alternate would be display youtube video thumbnails and allow the user to click on the thumbnail and open a separate activity to show the video but i would rather allow the user to play video in the cells of the listview what to you all think?

Answer (score -1):

How i did it

Download the youtube android SDK from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/) then get the jar file and copy it to libs folder on your app.

Enter this in dependency in gradle.build under dependencies

`compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')`

Syc and build.

Create an activity that extends YoutubeBaseActivity like below and implement the YoutubePlayer.OnInitializedListener as shown below. Override the methods on the interace. Android studio can help you do this.

```
public class Display extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
```

Then, when it loads successfully,

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean b) {
    if (!b) {
        player.cueVideo(videoID);
    }
}
```

This will load the youtube player and you play on the API

Happy coding, sorry am late

Comment: This does not answer the question. Inside a listview adapter is what is asked for.

Comment: True, my mistake. I had to start the playing on a new activity