# How can I use Youtube api in fragment which has a list view for Android

Tags: android, youtube-api

I want to use Youtube api to show videos in my list view. But my list view in a fragment. I'm confused about how can I do? I have tried all methods but no work.

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633683/android-playing-youtube-videos-using-youtube-player-api-in-listview